# javascript regex to match a combination of and/or expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a combination of and/or expression and match only sentences in between for example

```
test1 test2 and test2 or test4 test5
```

I want to get matches test1 test2, test2, test4 test5

I tried this regex https://regex101.com/r/FFLtg6/1 but it doesn't work :

```
(.+)(((and|or)\s+)?)+
```

Update : I need a regex expression because it is part of a bigger regex.

Comment: You don't need regex `match` method, use string `split` method. Try this: `"test1 test2 and test2 or test4 test5".split(/ and | or /);`

Comment: @EzioMercer I need a regex expression because it is part of a bigger regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use this regexp:

```js
const text = "test1 test2 and test2 or test4 test5";
const regexp = /(?<=^|and |or ).*?(?= and| or|$)/g;

console.log(text.match(regexp));
```

**P.S. But keep in mind that [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) feature is not supported in [all browsers](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)**

2. You can use this regexp which will not ignore all empty spaces around need parts:

```js
const text = "   test1 test2    and    test2    or    test4 test5   ";
const regexp = /\s*(?!and|or)\b.*?(?=and|or|$)/g;

console.log(text.match(regexp));
```

3. You can use this regexp which will ignore all empty spaces around need parts:

```js
const text = "    test1 test2    and    test2    or    test4 test5     ";
const regexp = /(?!and|or|\s)\b.*?(?=\s*(and|or|$))/g;

console.log(text.match(regexp));
```

Comment: Added one more regexp

Comment: Updated second and third regexps

Comment: Simplified 3rd regrexp

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you're looking for:

```js
const txt = "lorem ipsum and dolor and sit or amet consecteturand elit";

console.log(txt.split(/ and | or /));
```

Comment: good idea but I need a regex expression without using split because it is part of a bigger regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just do the obvious:

```
const rxWords = /\S+/g;
const rxConnectors = /^(and|or)$/i;
const nonConnector = w => ! rxConnectors.test(w) ;

function getInterestingWords( s ) {
  const corpus  = s ?? '' ;
  const matches = corpus.match( rxWords ) ;
  const words   = matches.filter( nonConnector ) ;

  return words;
}
```

Given that, executing

```
const text = 'test1 test2 and test2 or test4 test5f' ;
const interestingWords = getInterestingWords(text);
```

sets `interestingWords` to the expected

```
[ 'test1', 'test2', 'test2', 'test4', 'test5' ]
```